# How to collect variables from a tree formula

Tags: java

The question title might be poorly expressed, so I'm sorry for that. I am representing a propositional logic formula as a tree in Java, like so:

```
abstract class Formula { }

final class AndFormula extends Formula {
  private Formula leftChild, rightChild;

  public AndFormula(Formula leftChild, Formula rightChild) {
    this.leftChild = leftChild;
    this.rightChild = rightChild;
  }

  // add some getters...

}

final class OrFormula extends Formula {
  private Formula leftChild, rightChild;

  public OrFormula(Formula leftChild, Formula rightChild) {
    this.leftChild = leftChild;
    this.rightChild = rightChild;
  }

  // add some getters...

}

final class AtomicFormula extends Formula {
  private String name;

  public AtomicFormula(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  // add some getters...

}
```

Now let's say I want to collect the names of atomic formulas in a very particular way: I only want names of atomic formulas which never appear on the right hand side of an OrFormula. I have the following:

```
public static Set<String> specialVars(Formula f) {

  Set<String> ans = new HashSet<String>();

  if( f.getClass() == AndFormula.class ) {
    // Recursively add all special vars from the left child:
    ans.addAll( specialsVar( f.leftChild ) );

    // Recursively add all special vars from the right child:
    ans.addAll( specialsVar( f.rightChild ) );
  } else if( f.getClass() == OrFormula.class ) {
    // Recursively add all special vars from the left child:
    ans.addAll( specialsVar( f.leftChild ) );

    // Don't add anything from the right child!
  } else if( f.getClass() === AtomicFormula.class ) {
    // The base case:
    ans.add( f.getName() );
  }

  return ans;
}
```

This code seems to work, so my question is: is this idiomatic Java? If not, what would be the idiomatic way to write this code? Is there any unexpected behaviour I should be aware of?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) - it was designed to solve this kind of problem cleanly and extensibly

Comment: @wakjah Great, this is just the type of advice I'm looking for. Thanks!